# What are "reciprocal radii/radiuses"?

Tags: reference-request

in a novel I found the phrase "reciprocal radii". What exactly does this phrase mean? Can you explain it even for non-mathematicians, maybe in a more philosophical way (by connecting this phrase to a world view?) ?

Kind regards!

EDIT: Due to the commentary:

Ok, since the text is written in german I hope that I am translating the words correctly: together with that phrase comes

- "graphic representation of functions with complex variables"
- "the single human being as the unitary circle, in which Everything is reflected and twisted and contracted"
- "infinity becomes the deepest inner midpoint; and through this midpoint humans have crossed their coordinates."
- The author had some knowledge about Diophant, Euclid and Fermat; he very often writes about the earth being a circle or a globe. He also mentions Riemann occasionally.

maybe those information can help you and me :)

Comment: Could you give some more context? There are a number of areas where that phrase is used.

Comment: Sure! I edited my posting :)

Comment: I think you are talking about "inverting a circle".

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreisspiegelung) helps.

Comment: I have no idea what it means, but I see you're reading "Dark Mirrors" by Arno Schmidt. Trying to figure out this paragraph has brought me here.